# how to access a nested comprehensioned-list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a working solution for creating a list some of random numbers, count their occurrencies, and put the result in a dictionary which looks the following:

```
random_ints = [random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(6)]
dic = {x:random_ints.count(x) for x in set(random_ints)])
```

so that for, say [0,2,1,2,1,4] I get {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 4:1}

I was wondering if its possible to express this in a one liner, preferably without the use of a library function - I want to see what's possible with python :)
When I try to integrate the two lines in one I dont know howto express the two references to the same comprehensioned list of random_ints ..??? I expected something like:

```
dic = {x:random_ints.count(x) for x in set([random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(6)] as random_ints))
```

which of course does not work...

I looked (nested) list comprehensions up here on SO, but I could not apply the solutions I found to my problem.

thanks, s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to achieve something like that, but none of them is exactly what you want.  What you can't do is simple binding of a name to a fixed value inside the list/dict comprehension.  If `random_ints` does not depend on any of the iteration variables needed for `dic`, it's better to do it the way you did it, and create `random_ints` separately.

Conceptually, the only things that should be in the dict comprehension are the things that need to be created separately for each item in the dict.  `random_ints` doesn't meet this criterion; you only need one `random_ints` overall, so there's no reason to put it in the dict comprehension.

That said, one way to do it is to fake it by iterating over a one-element list containing your `random_ints`:

```
{x:random_ints.count(x) for random_ints in [[random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(6)]] for x in set(random_ints)}
```

Comment: So this fake iterating over the one-element-List (or 1-tuple like in @Schoolboy 's solution) is the way to get the comprehensioned-List named for further reference inside the main comprehension - cool. But it shouldn't be done 'cause its conceptionally not clean - even if I don't need the random-ints list any more. I think I got it :) - thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1243904: In general it's not Pythonic to try to squeeze things into one line just to be terse.  If it's more readable as two lines, just use two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner that relies on `random` and `collections` modules.

```
>>> import collections
>>> import random
>>> c = collections.Counter(random.randint(0, 6) for _ in range(100))
>>> c
Counter({2: 17, 1: 16, 0: 14, 3: 14, 4: 14, 5: 13, 6: 12})
```

Comment: Even though this uses a library module, it's qualitatively better than using `.count()` because it won't show quadratic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Using `as` in the <strike>list</strike> dict-comprehension won't work.

Try this:

```
dic = {x:random_ints.count(x)
       for random_ints in ([random.randint(0,4) for _ in range(6)],)
         for x in set(random_ints))
```

I think using `collections.Counter` is a better idea:

```
>>> import collections, random
>>> c = collections.Counter(random.randint(0, 6) for _ in range(6))
>>> c
Counter({6: 3, 0: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
```